# Rails form_tag, adding a hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `form_tag` that takes a code as input:

```
= form_tag({controller: "charges", action: "new"}, method: "get") do
  = label_tag(:code, "Check code:")
  = text_field_tag(:code)
  = hidden_field :item,  value: @item.id
  = submit_tag("Search")
```

I want to have a hidden field that adds a certain value to the URL. I basically want to create the URL `example.com/charges/new?item=1&code=mycode` where '1' is the item id and 'mycode' is the code entered by the user, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`hidden_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field) and [`hidden_field_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag) are not the same. You want the latter. `hidden_field` works like `text_field` and so requires an object (usually inside a `form_for`). `hidden_field_tag`, like `text_field_tag`, does not. This is a pretty common "gotcha" in Rails.

Try this:

```
= hidden_field_tag "item", @item.id
```

P.S. If this form is for creating a new model object (from your code I'm guessing it's for creating a Charge object), you probably want to use `form_for` instead. Something like this:

```
= form_for :charge do |f|
  = f.label :code, "Check code:"
  = f.text_field :code
  = f.hidden_field :item_id, @item.id
  = f.submit "Search"
```

This would probably simplify your controller a lot, since in your `create` action you could just do `Charge.create(params)`. I'm just guessing at what your actual models looks like, but it should give you the right idea. You should read through the [`form_for` docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) for more information.